# Laravel cashier-paddle not storing data in the database on payment success

Tags: php, laravel, subscription, laravel-cashier, paddle

I'm following the guidelines on the Laravel Documentation to configure the cashier-paddle package. But after successful payment using a sandbox account, it's not saving the entry in the local database, but the entry in the Paddle dashboard is present under customers.

web.php

```js
Route::get('/user/subscribe', function (Request $request) {
    $payLink = User::find(1)->newSubscription('default', $premium = 45680)
        ->returnTo('https://arqam-saleem.sharedwithexpose.com/')
        ->create();

    //print_r($payLink);

    return view('billing', ['paylink' => $payLink]);
})->name('user.subscribe');
```

Here is the Model

```
namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Paddle\Billable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    use Billable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

billing.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    @paddleJS
</head>
<body>
    <x-paddle-button :url="$paylink" class="px-8 py-4">
        Buy
    </x-paddle-button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Expose to create a public URL to add to the Paddle dashboard for receiving webhooks. But it's still not working. Any idea why it's happening? I can share more details if needed.

In Paddle's notification logs, all are marked as failed or retrying which will ultimately be failed.

**Note:** It's a local environment on Windows.

Webhook settings screenshots from Paddle Dashboard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your problem is definitely with your webhook setup. Can you please show your webhook setup? Can you share your event handlers if possible?

Comment: @oralunal, I have added the screenshots of the Paddle dashboard. I have not setup any event listener myself. I am assuming that the cashier will handle it by himself. If you want me to go into the cashier package and share the listner code from there then let me know.

Comment: You should set event listener, btw, paddle will update your database with webhooks.. You have to catch the request with event listeners and process them.